# Prime number if else error

Tags: c, if-statement

```
//Prime test
    if(iSelectedOp == 6 )
    {
        printf("Enter positive integer to be tested: \n");
        scanf("%d", &dInteger1);
        int i;
        int f;
        for (i= 2; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (num1 % i == 0);
                f++;
                printf("%d is prime\n", dInteger1);
            else    
                printf("no prime\n");
            }

    }
```

hey all, I have here a function that takes an input number and tells the user if it's prime or no. I'm receiving an error that says i have an else without a previous if. I'm sure it's some syntax thing I'm missing. Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the `;` from the first if.

Comment: And putting `{` curly brackets `}` around the `f++; printf(...);`.

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one statement following your inner if, so it needs brackets

```
if (num1 % i == 0)
{
    f++;
    printf("%d is prime\n", dInteger1);
}
else    
    printf("no prime\n");
```

Also, you had an extra semicolon after the `if`.

To avoid confusion and make code easier to read, I will typically use {} whether or not they are needed.  This is a point of style, though, and not absolutely necessary.

```
if (num1 % i == 0)
{
    f++;
    printf("%d is prime\n", dInteger1);
}
else    
{
    printf("no prime\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (num1 % i == 0);
                  ^ delete this
```

It should be:

```
if (num1 % i == 0) {
    f++;
    printf("%d is prime\n", dInteger1);
} else {
    printf("no prime\n");
}
```

Without curly braces, `if` (and `while`, `for`, etc) statements's bodies only go until the `;` (so for `if (true) a(); b();`, `a()` is the only part covered by the `if`; `b()` is always executed, as it's outside of the scope of the `if`).

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after your `if` statement, which prevents an `else` from following.  On a related note, I don't think your implementation will work at all...  This might be closer to what you're looking for:

```
    bool prime = true;
    for (i = 2; i*i <= dInteger1; i++)
    {
        if (dInteger1 % i == 0)
            prime = false;
    }
    if(prime)
        printf("%d is prime\n", dInteger1);
    else
        printf("no prime\n");
```